# Json массив в HTML таблицу

Tags: javascript, html, json, html5

Есть json фаил с данными на 8000 строк. Его данные нужно перенести в HTML таблицу.
 Поиск по просторам интернета не дал результата.

```
            <table id= "userdata">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <td>Count</td>
                  <td>Total</td>
                  <td>Amount</td>
                  <td>Price</td>
                  <td>Price</td>
                  <td>Amount</td>
                  <td>Total</td>
                  <td>Count</td>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                 <tr>
                  <td>здесь должны быть данные из numberOfOrders</td>
                  <td>здесь должны быть данные из price</td>
                  <td>здесь должны быть данные из quantity</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
                  <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

Соответственно, как сделать что бы таблица строилась сама когда брала данные из массива?

```
{
  "name": "BTC/USD",
  "asks": [
{
  "numberOfOrders": 1,
  "price": 6074.9,
  "quantity": 3.93318116
}, {
  "numberOfOrders": 1,
  "price": 6080,
  "quantity": 0.01
}, {
  "numberOfOrders": 1,
  "price": 6081.04,
  "quantity": 34.6
}
```

Comment: Тебе поможет метод `appendChild()`. Вставляешь в таблицу  через цикл `elem.asks[i].numberOfOrders`

Comment: Можно использовать какой-нибудь простой static site generator типа http://assemble.io

Comment: Сторонние ресурсы использовать нельзя.

Comment: @user302239 Данные приходят строго в таком формате? Количество полей всегда одинаковое? Что за пустые `td` в примере кода?

Comment: по поводу td. я вот и не знаю можно ли сделать, что бы они сами вставали с данными из массива json и из html их убрать. или нужно сделать архитектуру в html и туда как то подставлять данные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var aData = {
  "name": "BTC/USD",
  "asks": [{
    "numberOfOrders": 1,
    "price": 6074.9,
    "quantity": 3.93318116
  }, {
    "numberOfOrders": 1,
    "price": 6080,
    "quantity": 0.01
  }, {
    "numberOfOrders": 1,
    "price": 6081.04,
    "quantity": 34.6
  }]
}

xJSON = JSON.stringify(aData);

function fBuildTable(oData) {
  var oTBody = document.getElementById('userdata').tBodies[0];
  var oAsks = oData['asks'];
  oAsks.forEach(function(oItem) {
    var oRow = oTBody.insertRow();
    for (key in oItem) {
      var oCell = oRow.insertCell();
      oCell.innerHTML = oItem[key];
    }
  });
}

fBuildTable(JSON.parse(xJSON));
```

```css
#userdata {
  border: 2px solid #f00;
}

#userdata td {
  border: 1px dotted #080;
}
```

```html
<table id="userdata">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Count</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>здесь должны быть данные из numberOfOrders</td>
      <td>здесь должны быть данные из price</td>
      <td>здесь должны быть данные из quantity</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все получилось